# FacebookClient verify access token in C#

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to verify a user access token in the backend in C# using FacebookClient, I have found another answer here on stackoverflow that said you can check it with one line `var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");`, it seems to accept any access tokens without throwing an error, how do I check if it's still valid?

Comment: Still looking for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that when you create your object.

However, when you try to use your facebook client, e.g. doing a call to Facebook API, the client will throw an error if the access token is invalid.